# jQuery UI not working for accordion

Tags: jquery-ui

my html looks like this

```
<div id="menu">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>I'm the first section!</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>I'm the second section!</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <div>
            <p>I'm the third section!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').accordion();
});
```

Somehow my accordion is not working even though I took this directly off of codeacademy. Previously, I had made my own accordion and it wasn't working so I took it off codeacademy where i first learnt it and still it wasn't working. I am hosting off google. Is something wrong with this?

I tried adding header: 'h3'

but it still has no effect. It just looks like an alternate of h3 and divs.

Comment: Have you actually included the `jquery-ui.js` script to your page?

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/596/) - have you added jquery and the jquery-ui javascript files? Any errors in the console?

Comment: yes i have. both of them from google. And there are no errors at all it just behaves as if nothing has been done to them. I tried adding a few jquery alert on click commands and they work, just not the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link to jquery should come before jquery UI or else it would not work.